# Why am I receiving "Connection reset by peer (104)" error when testing server with ab?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, web

I am writing a Web Server that uses threaded architecture in Python3. The way I realize it is by having the main thread accepting and adding incoming connections to a queue. Again in the main thread I distribute the connections in the queue between 10 threads each having its own list of connections. Basically I am filling the thread's connection list. The threads never stop running. They use select to handle all of the connections in their list. (The sockets are non-blocking). The algorithm is simple:

```
On Thread:
read, write, error = select.select(self.connections, self.connections, self.connections)

for sock in read:
    recv_data = sock.recv(128)
    if recv_data:
        self.handlers[sock].handle(recv_data)
    else
        # Client disconnected
        self.connections.remove(sock)

for sock in write:
    if self.handlers[sock].has_output():
        while self.handlers[sock].has_output():
            sock.send(self.handlers[sock].get_output()
    elif self.handlers[sock].should_close():
        sock.shutdown(0)
        sock.close()
        self.connections.remove(sock)
        del self.handlers[sock]
```

Now the handle method just returns the data it receives and sets the should_close flag to true. Using that algorithm my server handles most of the incoming connections, but there is a problem. When I run the following test

```
ab -n 1000 -c 1000 127.0.0.1:27015/
Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
Completed 1000 requests
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 3000 requests
Completed 4000 requests
Completed 5000 requests
Completed 6000 requests
Completed 7000 requests
Completed 8000 requests
Completed 9000 requests
apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104)
Total of 9320 requests completed
```

some of the request do not complete. I get the error "Connection reset by peer (104)". From researching I found out that the error occurs when a connection is closed before the received data is handled. The server does not give errors, nor does python throw any exceptions.

Here is the complete thread code:
http://pastebin.com/arUyNnyj

My question is what exactly is causing the tests to fail? Is the error inside my server logic or is it because of something else?

Here is the complete code that I am using:
[Source on GitHub](https://github.com/IceCubeDev/CodeSnippets-Projects/tree/master/Telebid-Tasks/WebServer/web/threaded)